# downloading an intended web page by a browser plugin or a widows application

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, plugins

Is it possible to write a browser plugin or a windows or linux application that can download each currently opened web page that is now running in our browser? Do any one have any similar method for this purpose?

Comment: Extensions can use chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML or manually extract html from each tab and its resources via chrome.debugger API method [Page.getResourceTree](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-getResourceTree). Another method is using a content script to get html from DOM and resources from performance.getEntries() and download each one individually.

Comment: Tanks a lot. Now is it possible to download just js part of we page separated from html file? And also is it possible to write a plugin to monitor JS event of a web page

Comment: What is a "js part" and "js event" exactly?

Comment: JS part: javascript part of all web page code that i assume often it is external./// JS event: for example a call to time functions or assignments or etc.

Comment: I don't understand. If it's a script with its own URL then it's already covered in my first comment. As for a call to a function or assignment, there's no magic universal solution but in most cases an extension can do it with chrome.debugger API which provides access to the same stuff used by devtools.

Comment: consider a situation that the number of calling performance.now() in a page is important for us. I mean is there any tool or possibility to monitor this calls?

Comment: A global function is easy to monitor - an extension can reassign window.performance.now or window.Performance.prototype.now in [page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) to a wrapper function that calls the original function and updates the statistics.